# Add mdKeyBoard to javascript added element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bewkj5da)

I am trying to add mdKeyBoard to dynamically created element, It works for `textarea` present in DOM, but not for the one which added through javascript.

Tried to `$compile` also still of no use.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial', 'material.components.keyboard']);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$compile) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $compile(angular.element(document.getElementById('idTextArea')))($scope);     
 }, 1000);
});

//JS-library
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'off');
textarea.setAttribute('use-keyboard', 'US International');
textarea.setAttribute('id', 'fabricTextArea');
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(textarea);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidenke/angular-material-keyboard/9365d06c/dist/mdKeyboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidenke/angular-material-keyboard/9365d06c/dist/mdKeyboard.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <md-input-container>
        <textarea type="text" id='text_tool' aria-label='demo'
                  use-keyboard='US International'
                  ng-model="WBCtrl.textFieldValue">
        </textarea>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `setTimeout` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a more fundamental problem. In AngularJS DOM manipulation should be done in directives. Avoid doing DOM manipulation in controllers.

To dynamically add elements in AngularJS use the [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<textarea ng-if="addTextarea" autocapitalize='off'
          use-keyboard='US International' ng-model="fabricValue"
          id='fabricTextArea' >
</textarea>
```

In the controller, use `$scope.addTextarea=true` to have the AngularJS framework dynamically add the element.

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/VvUxWC3TA1d3oxgBIi2O?p=preview)

The `use-keyboard` directive needs the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) which is instantiated by the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial', 'material.components.keyboard']);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$compile) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $compile(angular.element(document.getElementById('fabricTextArea')))($scope);     
 }, 1000);
});

//JS-library
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'off');
textarea.setAttribute('use-keyboard', 'US International');
textarea.setAttribute('id', 'fabricTextArea');
textarea.setAttribute('ng-model', 'xxx');
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(textarea);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
<link href="//unpkg.com/angular-material-keyboard/dist/mdKeyboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//unpkg.com/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-material-keyboard/dist/mdKeyboard.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <md-input-container>
        <textarea type="text" id='text_tool' aria-label='demo'
                  use-keyboard='US International'
                  ng-model="WBCtrl.textFieldValue">
        </textarea>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```